# "E492 no es un comando del editor :PlugInstall"

Tags: vim

hace dos días instale neovim, lo configure y todo bien funciona el editor, el problema es cuando intento instalar plugins no me deja me sale el error "E492 no es un comando del editor :PlugInstall", desde que lo instale estoy buscando como solucionarlo y no encuentro solución. Si alguien me pudiera ayudar porque no encuentro como solucionarlo[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pareciera que estás usando https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug como instalador de plugins, chequea la instalación (revisa el enlace) y en todo caso comparte tu archivo `. vimrc`

Comment: Y por cierto, Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Amigo pudiste solucionar el error?, tengo el mismo problema con mi terminal de ubuntu pero no con la de Powershell

Answer (score 0):

Esto puede pasar cuando no encuentra el archivo /autoload/plug.vim que se requiere para utilizar [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) y poder instalar diferentes plug-ins.

Para solucionarlo debes revisar que el archivo [plug.vim](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim) se encuentre en tu directorio de instalación de vim, en mi caso sería **`(C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim82\autoload)`**

También puedes revisar que el archivo [plug.vim](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim) se encuentre en el directorio de usuario, en mi caso sería **`C:\Users\MyUserManuel\vimfiles\autoload`**